# fmap versus <$>

Tags: haskell

According to the documentation `<$>` is an synonym for `fmap` and they have the following types:

```
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

So it seems to me, from the signatures above, that they take the arguments in the same order, the only difference being that one is infix and the other is not. I have two pieces of code, one using `fmap`, and the other using `<$>`. Why is it that only the former runs correctly?

```
import Control.Applicative
main :: IO ()
main = do
  [x, y] <- map read . words <$> getLine
  putStrLn $ show (x + y)
```

This one won't compile:

```
import Control.Applicative
main :: IO ()
main = do
  [x, y] <- map read . fmap words getLine
  putStrLn $ show (x + y)
```

Comment: Due to operator precedence compared with the `.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Precedence of operators is expressed as an integer between 0 and 9, while function application effectively has precedence 10 (higher than any operator).

`(.)` has very high precedence (9), while `(<$>)` has lower precedence (4), resulting in your first expression being parsed as

```
((map read) . words) <$> getLine
```

while your second expression is parsed as

```
(map read) . (fmap words getLine)
```

resulting in an attempt to compose an `IO [String]` value with a function of type `[String] -> [a]`.

Comment: I don't understand why it's parsed as `((map read) . words) <$> getLine`. For example I read `f . g` as "f after g". So in your example why does `map read` go first?

Comment: oh forget about it. function application has higher precedence as you just said.

Comment: @plx: By the way, you can find the precedence of an operator easily using the `:info`/`:i` command in GHCi. For example, `:i .` shows `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’` `infixr 9 .`

Answer (score 7):

This is due to *operator precedence*. If we look at the source code, we see that:

```
infixl 4 <$>
infixr 9  .
```

So that means that if you write:

```
  map read . words  <$> getLine
```

Haskell sees this as:

```
(map read . words) <$> getLine
```

But if you write:

```
 map read  .  fmap words getLine
```

Haskell sees this as:

```
(map read) . (fmap words getLine)
```

So the arguments of `fmap` are different.

If we however *add brackets*, the two will be equivalent:

```
import Control.Applicative

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [x, y] <- map read . (words <$> getLine)
  putStrLn $ show (x + y)
```